# Laplacian on a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be an $n$-dimensional Lie group over $\mathbb R$ (I am happy to assume $G$ is compact) and $(V_1,\dots,V_n$) a basis for its Lie algebra, $\mathfrak g$. Viewing the $V_i$ as left-invariant vector fields on $G$, they act linearly $C^{\infty}(G)\to C^{\infty}(G)$ by $$V_if(x):=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(X_t^x)-f(x)}{t},$$
where $$\dot X_t^x=V_i(X_t^x), \quad X_0^x=x\in G.$$ We can then build another linear operator $L:C^{\infty}(G)\to C^{\infty}(G),\; L=\sum_i V_i^2$, where $V_i^2= V_i\circ V_i$.

---

Letting $\mu$ be a left Haar measure on $G$ and $f,g\in C_c^{\infty}(G)$ smooth functions of compact support, do we have the identity $$\int_GLf(x)g(x)\mu(dx)=\int_Gf(x)Lg(x)\mu(dx)?$$ I.e., is $L$ symmetric on $L^2(G,\mu)$?
I've tried fiddling around with the above definitions, but seem only to arrive at massive, unrevealing formulae!

Comment: sure, as long as $\mu$ is also right-invariant (which is true for compact $G$'s): just use that for any left-invariant vector field $V$ you have $\int_G V(fg)\mu=0$ ($L_V\mu=0$ since $\mu$ is right-invariant) and so $\int_G (Vf)g\mu=-\int_G fVg\mu$

Comment: As @user8268 says... and then to obtain the actual Casimir/Laplacian (up to sign...), you'd want the $\{V_i\}$ to be orthonormal with respect to the Killing form, not just an arbitrary basis. But/and the symmetry holds for each $V_i\circ V_i$, regardless.

Comment: @user8268 Thanks -- I don't completely understand, though! Would you mind explaining your notation? What's $L_V$? And why does right-invariance of $\mu$ imply that $L_V\mu = 0$? If you could flesh that out into an answer, I would gladly accept! Also, am I right in thinking that the same argument would show, for example, that $T:=\left(\sum_j V_j^2\right)^2$ is symmetric?

Comment: $L_V$ stands for the Lie derivative w.r.t. $V$ (not sure whether you know this language). Briefly: left-invariant vector fields generate the right translations, that's why $L_V\mu=0$ means that $\mu$ is right invariant. For your last question - yes.

Comment: @paulgarrett: If $G$ is not semisimple, the Killing form might be degenerate; wouldn't this be bothersome? Think of $G$ commutative.

Comment: @AlexM., true, the commutative case (or having commutative factors) is special...